# Different ways to set context?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here are two ways of setting context:

```
$.proxy(function() { 
  this.doStuff();
}, this);
```

...

```
var that = this;
that.doStuff();
```

Is there any reason to use one and not the other?

Comment: of curse that if you use less functions it will be faster ...

Comment: You might want to read up on JS scopes, context and what `this` can reference at any given moment. Also: come more context might be useful. Remeber, too, that your first snippet uses jQuery(?), whereas your second doesn't

Comment: There's also `.call()` and `.apply()` and `.bind()` ...

Comment: The anonymous function is useless. Use `$.proxy(this.doStuff, this)` or `$.proxy(this, "doStuff")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second approach is pure javascript.

The first one rely on a framework (jQuery in your case).

There is no one better than other.

I prefer the second one which is framework free.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use bind.

```
this.ans = 42;
this.fun = function() { alert(this.ans) };
var binded_fun = this.fun.bind(this);
binded_fun() // 42
```

Also you can use bind for сurrying, for example:

```
var sum = function(a, b) { return a + b };
var add5 = sum.bind(this, 5);
alert(add5(3)) // 8
```

Function 'bind' exist in modern browsers as are native code and faster than jQuery.proxy http://jsperf.com/bind-vs-jquery-proxy

In old browsers you can implement it https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind